# Bitcoin address to private key,

Tags: private-key, bitcoin

I know its impossible to calculate a Bitcoin private key from address, but how far beck can you go with math, where math stops?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the address is a public key to your private key. Thus, it is a classic problem for asymmetric encryption to recover a private key from a known public one, which rests on the task of decomposing a large integer into prime multiplicities.